# Xcode 3.2.6: an issue with the Cocos2d Framework

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, xcodebuild

I'm using XCode 3.2.6. I'd like to make my game work for earlier version 3.1.3 but when I build the Project in Xcode, I'm getting the following error:

```
File /Users/.../build/Debug-iphoneos/libcocos2d libraries.a depends on itself.  This target might include its own product.
```

And it's the only error. What's the meaning of this error? What's the issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason your Cocos2d library depends on itself. Open the properties for your Cocos2d library target (right click -> "Get Info") and look at the general tab. There's a list called "DirectDependencies". Remove the cocos2d library from that list.

Another place where a direct dependency could occur is the Cocos2d library product. Open the properties for your Cocos2d library product (this time under "Products" not under "Targets"). Open the targets tab and look at the targets. If the cocos2d library is checked as target, uncheck it.